Installing **global** nuget tool from **local file** (nupkg) without visual studio using cmd or powershell
I'm trying install dotnet-ef tools. For some reason i have no access to nuget site from cli.
I successfully downloaded nupkg file so its in my C:\Downloads folder as dotnet-ef.9.0.0-preview.3.24172.4.nupkg.
I found no ways to install it.
Here some commands, that don't work:
Install-Package SomePackage -Source C:\Downloads\dotnet-ef.9.0.0-preview.3.24172.4.nupkg

...uses for local packages from NuGet.
Install-Package C:\Downloads\dotnet-ef.9.0.0-preview.3.24172.4.nupkg

...do nothing:
PS C:\Windows\system32> Install-Package C:\Downloads\dotnet-ef.9.0.0-preview.3.24172.4.nupkg
PS C:\Windows\system32>

Thanks!

dotnet tool install dotnet-ef --version 9.0.0-preview.3.24172.4 --global --add-source C:\Downloads (though I would just get it from NuGet in the first place...)

@MartinCostello finally:
PS C:\Windows\system32> dotnet tool install dotnet-ef --version 9.0.0-preview.3.24172.4 --global --add-source C:\Downloads
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Package

Name                           Version          Source                           ProviderName
----                           -------          ------                           ------------
dotnet-ef                      9.0.0-preview... C:\Program Files\PackageManag... NuGet
...

Great answer!
